# TurboC Dosbox changing windows using Super+Tab or Alt+Tab

Tags: shortcut-keys, c, dosbox

I use Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, I recently installed and configured Turbo C on dosbox, i attend online courses and use Turbo C to practice.
Is there a way that i can use super+tab or alt+tab to change between full-screened dos window and chrome?
Are there any other shortcuts?

Thanks in advance ^_^